# how to store this data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am working a php script that gathers and stores links into mysql, the problem I have is that sometimes my script gets multiple links for the same download such as this:

```
http://www.fileserve.com/file/XXXXXX
http://www.fileserve.com/file/XXXXXX
http://www.filesonic.com/file/0000000
http://www.filesonic.com/file/0000000
http://www.uploadstation.com/file/AAAAAAA
http://www.uploadstation.com/file/AAAAAAA
```

Right now I am storing them into a table with information such as the ID, Title, and download links, problem is that they are all in one row, it will be hard to organize and sort them in the output later on? My script currently supports over 20 filehosts so I couldn't make a row for each individual one.

So I guess I need a way to organize the output of the links (grouped accordingly mainly), or a better way to store them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use a one to many relationship

What I would do is have a `songs` table with `id,name,title,artist` etc, and then a `links` table that has a `id,url, and song_id` where `song_id` points to the songs.id column.

That way you can have one, or you can 50 links for each song.

check out this for more info
http://www.tekstenuitleg.net/en/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/one-to-many.html

Answer (score 0):

You may split it into two tables.

Table 1:
[FileName] [FileID]

Table 2:
[FileID] [LinkID] [URL]

If you want to retrieve the download link for a file later, you may use

```
SELECT URL FROM TABLE1 T1,TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.FileID = T2.FileID ORDER BY LinkID ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create 2 tables.

First table stores `Title_Id` and `Title`

Second table stores `Titele_Id` and `Links`(1 link each row,so there will be many rows with same `Title_Id`)

Storing all links in a single row is bad because what if some row has 2 links,some has 5 links,some has just one.This will lead to many empty columns and is bad design

Answer (score -1):

You can use [json](http://php.net/json_encode), as the links will become a string you can store in a single row.

```
$links = array();
$links[] = 'http://www.fileserve.com/file/XXXXXX';
$links[] = 'http://www.fileserve.com/file/XXXXXX';
$links[] = 'http://www.filesonic.com/file/0000000';
$links[] = 'http://www.filesonic.com/file/0000000';
$links[] = 'http://www.uploadstation.com/file/AAAAAAA';
$links[] = 'http://www.uploadstation.com/file/AAAAAAA';

$encoded_for_db = json_encode($links);
```

later on decode

```
$decoded = json_decode($links); //and returns same array
```

Comment: Not a good idea. It works, but you can't do any query on the links because it's just a string now.

Comment: he didn't said he wants to query the links, he just needs to get them organised ... same order he put them in

Comment: Mihai, that basically makes a RDBMS useless. Your solution works, sure, but it doesn't make it good. You will not be able to do anything with a string. If you have a *relational* DBMS at your disposition, you shouldn't be afraid to make use of its full potential!

Comment: so you rather use multiple query's to get some encoded links that you can't possibly query them as the don't have the file name in the path. I was pointing a sollution in storing tons of links that can't be query'd and displaying them later on